# Android icon ic_menu_save not present in Android Design icons

Tags: android, icons, android-image, imageicon

I have downloaded the Android Design Icons from the android website. To be specific its Android Design - Icons 20131120, the one I have downloaded on my pc. What I need is the ic_menu_save (64x64 in dimension) icon which is not present in the folder Core_Icons\unstyled\xhdpi. This icon is whitish/transparent when you see it at first glance. Where do I find this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think android icon has been updated and you can find save icon in this folder 
"Android_Design_Icons_20131106\Android Design - Icons 20131120\Action Bar Icons\holo_light\05_content_save"

Hope this might help you a bit.

Answer (score 2):

if you are looking for this icon [image]

you can get this in Action bar icons as menu has been replaced with Actionbar and the below is the link for the Actionbar icons

https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html

in this webpage Action bar Icon pack, click on the Action Bar Icon pack blue button to download those images

there will be holo light and holo dark images, you can find grey or white as per your requirement you can that particular image in 05_content_save folder of all the sizes

Comment: My pleasure buddy Miss LC